# What could explain a mismatch in timing within a Typescript async function vs. outside the function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, timing

Trying to track down a time bottleneck in some front-end code running in the browser.

```
  private async waitForLoad(timeout: number) {
    console.time("Inside WFL");
    let count = 0;

    while (this.getSignedIn() && !auth.currentUser) {
      await this.delay(10);
      count = count + 10;
      if (count >= timeout) {
        break;
      }
    }
    console.timeEnd("Inside WFL");
  }

  public async getToken(timeout: number): Promise<string> {
    console.time("Outside WFL");
    await this.waitForLoad(timeout);
    console.timeEnd("Outside WFL");

    if (auth.currentUser) {
      const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
      return token;
    } else {
      console.log("Auth: tried to get token on null user");
      throw new Error("Not signed in");
    }
  }
```

From the console:

```
Inside WFL: 0.112060546875 ms
Outside WFL: 100.983154296875 ms
```

Why would these two measurements be so drastically different?

Comment: What are `getSignedIn()` and `delay()`?

Comment: How often do you call `awaitForLoad()`? Is `getToken()` the only place where you call it?

Comment: It is only called once.  No external asynchronous invocations.  `getSignedIn()` checks global state for signed in status and `delay` throttles the tight loop.  In this case, neither of those functions were called because `auth.currentUser` was not null.

Comment: Then the only thing that could explain this would be a helluva other promise jobs (possibly synchronous and long-running?) clogging up the promise job queue.

Comment: (Btw, don't poll the global state in a "tight" loop. Instead of polling, create a promise for being/becoming signed in and resolve that when you change the state; or fire an event and listen for that in `waitForLoad`.)

Comment: Okay, running the next app using `next start` vs. dev mode `next dev` drops "Outside WFL" to ~25ms... which is much better but still has me wondering how to improve it.  Is there a way to inspect the promise job queue?

Comment: Not that I know, but stepping through the end of the function (i.e. placing a breakpoint on `onsole.timeEnd("Inside WFL");`, then going step by step forward / into) with a debugger might reveal the other handlers. Also possibly some async_hooks machinery. And it might be possible to use those [async_hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) to do some logging.

Answer (score 0):

> would these two measurements be so drastically different?

They wouldn't be. The function is probably running again and again and you are getting confused in the co-relation.

## More

Simplified reproducable example:

```
const delay = (timeout: number) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, timeout));

async function waitForLoad(timeout: number) {
    console.time("Inside WFL");
    await delay(timeout);
    console.timeEnd("Inside WFL");
}

async function getToken(timeout: number): Promise<void> {
    console.time("Outside WFL");
    await waitForLoad(timeout);
    console.timeEnd("Outside WFL");
}

getToken(1000);
```

Results:

```
Inside WFL: 1003.980712890625 ms
Outside WFL: 1004.201171875 ms
```

Comment: I understand that conceptually they wouldn't be different.  However, in my case they are which is why I didn't simplify my example. Could you edit your answer to elaborate on how I am "confused in the co-relation"?